# import TensorFlow: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to learn to use TensorFlow but, of course, I am not even able to install it!

These are the info about my case:

- Python 3.6 64-bit
- Intel(R) HD Graphics 520
- Intel i7
- Windows 7
- numpy 1.14.1

I have followed these steps:

1. On cmd: `C:\> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu`
2. On Python: `import tensorflow`

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VES\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 62, in preload_check
    ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.nvcuda_dll_name)
  File "C:\Users\VES\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\VES\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\VES\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\VES\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\VES\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 70, in preload_check
    % build_info.nvcuda_dll_name)
ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Typically it is installed in 'C:\Windows\System32'. If it is not present, ensure that you have a CUDA-capable GPU with the correct driver installed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run TensorFlow with GPU support you'll need an NVIDIA graphic card and the CUDA libraries installed (see [requirements here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu)), unfortunately your *Intel(R) HD Graphics 520* won't do.

You can settle for the CPU version (`pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`), which is still good to start learning.

**UPDATE**: another solution is to use the online service [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com), which allows you to borrow a GPU from Google's cloud infrastructure for learning purposes.

Comment: man.. you have solved my sufferings! I have settled the CPU version and now it works. thanks!!